# Display Validation Message

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have an XML layout file that contains an `EditText` and a `Button`. I would like to display the following validation message to provide feedback to the user:

> You must enter 4 numbers

What's the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my experience, this is the best way:

```
EditText yourEditText;

// when you detect an error:
yourEditText.setError("Input must be 4 digits and numeric");
```

The result is:

[image]

Also, if the input must be numeric, use `android:inputType="numberSigned"` in the `EditText` definition. That way the device won't allow the user to put non-numeric values; even better, it will show a special keyboard to do so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the EditText definition in the xml use [android:numeric](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3anumeric) to bring up the numeric IME and use [android:maxLength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxLength) = "4" to limit the input to 4 digits. Use [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) on the button to trigger a click handler.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(mEditText.length() != 4) { // check if 4 digits
        Toast.makeText(this, "Input must be 4 digits and numeric", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```